# AWS service for custom rules to trigger at scheduled times for specific events

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a workflow where I need to pass in some information that would be stored for a period of time, and then sends off a trigger after a scheduled period of time with the same information.

I considered using a TTL on a dynamo db table, but I was wondering if I could use cloudwatch events for this since it seems ideal as it has cron expressions for cloudwatch rules.

I know I can setup a cloudwatch rule to trigger say every 15 minutes, but how do I setup cloudwatch such that only my custom information gets picked up by this rule and I can pass some information into this event so that when the trigger gets sent to the target, my custom information is sent to the target as well?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB TTL is a bad fit as you don’t get a ton of granularity.

You can use the CloudWatch events PutEvent api to put a custom event. That should get you where you want.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/AddEventsPutEvents.html

Comment: Thanks Chris. I wanted to know if it's possible for the custom event to be triggered at a specific rate, say for example I fire off 100 custom events, and then they all only get triggered at say 11 pm at night to send the details specific to a queue?

Comment: I'm considering using step functions wait state for this, and keep step functions for more of the workflow as well, since I feel it might not be possible to do this with just cloudwatch.